# How Do Applications handle Asynchronous Responses - via Callback

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, asynchronous, callback

I have been doing Java for a few years but I have not had much experience with Asynchronous programming.

I am working on an application that makes SOAP web service calls to some Synchronous web services and currently the implementation of my *consuming* application is Synchronous also ie. my applications threads block while waiting for the response.

I am trying to learn how to handle these SOAP calls in an asynchronous way - just for the hell of it but I have some high-level questions which I cant seem to find any answers to.

I am using CXF but my question is not specifically about CXF or SOAP, but higher-level, in terms of asynchronous application architecture I think.

### What I want to know (working thru a scenario) - at a high level - is:

1. So I have a Thread (`A`) running in my JVM that makes a call to a remote web service
2. It *registers* a `callback` method and returns a `Future`
3. Thread (`A`) has done its bit and gets returned to its pool once it has returned the `Future`
4. The remote web service response returns and Thread (`B`) gets allocated and calls the `callback` method (which generally populates the `Future` with a result I believe)

Q1. I cant get my head off the blocking thread model - if Thread (A) is no longer listening to that network socket then how does the response that comes back from the remote service get allocated Thread (B) - is it simply treated as a new request coming into the server/container which then allocates a thread to service it?

Q2. Closely related to Q1 I imagine: if no Thread has the `Future`, or `handler` (with its `callback` method) on its stack, then how does the response from the remote web service get associated with the callback method it needs to call?

Or, in another way of asking, how does Thread `B` (now dealing with the response) get given a reference to the `Future`/`Callback` object?

---

Very sorry my question is so long - and thanks to anyone who gave their time to read through it! :)

Comment: Are you trying to understand the current behavior of your application OR are you planning to redesign your application so that it behaves in asynchronous manner?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you'd add all this complexity using asynchronous Threading.

The way to design an asynchronous soap service:
You have one service sending out a response to a given client / clients.
Those clients work on the response given asynchronously. 
When done, they would call another soap method to return their response.
The response will just be stored in a queue (e.g. a database table), without any extra logic. You'd have a "Worker" Service working on the incoming tasks. If a response is needed again another method on the other remote service would be called. The requests I would store as events in the database, which would later be asynchronously handled by an EventHandler. See
Hexagonal Architecture:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGaJHEgonKg

Answer (score 0):

Your Q1 and Q2 seem to have more to do with multithreading than they have to do with asynchronous calls.

The magic of asynchronous web service calls is that you don't have to worry about multithreading to handle blocking while waiting for a response.

It's a bit unclear from the question what the specific problem statement is (i.e., what you are hoping to have your application do while blocking or rather than blocking), but here are a couple ways that you could use asynchronous web service calls that will allow you to do other work.

For the following cases, assume that the dispatch() method calls [Dispatch.invokeAsync(T msg, AsyncHandler handler)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Dispatch.html#invokeAsync(T,%20javax.xml.ws.AsyncHandler)) and returns a [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html):

1) Dispatch multiple web service requests, so that they run in parallel:

If you have multiple services to consume and they can all execute independently, dispatch them all at once and process the responses when you have received them all.

```
ArrayList<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<?>>(); 
futures.add(serviceToConsume1.dispatch());
futures.add(serviceToConsume2.dispatch());
futures.add(serviceToConsume3.dispatch());

// now wait until all services return
for(Future f<?> : futures) {
    f.get();
}

// now use responses to continue processing
```

2) Polling:

```
Future<?> f = serviceToConsume.dispatch();

while(!f.isDone()) {
    // do other work here
}

// now use response to continue processing
```